# Is that possible to use multiple output in Azure Functions .Net 5?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, .net-5

I'm using .net 5 azure function with ServiceBus. I want to send multiple messages from trigger function.
In previous version you could usr IAsyncCollector to do something like that:

```cs
[FunctionName("HttpToServiceBusQueue")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [ServiceBus("testqueue",Connection ="connectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> outputEvents,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    // ...
    
    await outputEvents.AddAsync("message1");
    await outputEvents.AddAsync("message2");

    // ...
    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

But as I read there in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions) is no support of IAsyncCollector in newer version.
Is there any alternative ways to do it or?

Example of my code:

```cs
[Function("FileTriggerFunction")]
[ServiceBusOutput("fileupload", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionWrite")]
public string Run(
    [BlobTrigger("file-storage/{name}", Connection = "ConnectionString")] string  myBlob, string name,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var logger = context.GetLogger("FileTriggerFunction");
    var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(*List of messages*);
    logger.LogInformation(res);
    return res;
}
```

Actually it separates each object of list for separate message, but I don't think that it is correct to do this in such way.

Comment: I recommend using the ServiceBus client to send messages. That's essentially what `IAsyncCollector` was doing except this way you control retry behavior and can detect and log/handle errors.

Comment: If you want to output multiple messages to the same service bus instance, then Stephen is right. Not you can add multiple output bindings (of different types) to output data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code how to do it

```
    [Function("MultiOutput")]
    public static DispatchedMessages Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        return new DispatchedMessages
        {
            Messages = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb" } // todo: serialize
        };
    }

    public class DispatchedMessages
    {
        [ServiceBusOutput(queueOrTopicName: "dest", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: When sending lots of big items like this, they are all collected in memory before they are sent. Is there a better way for this case?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of IAsyncCollector we have multiple output binding in .net 5

On this function we will give the multiple output values.

```
public static class MultiOutput
{
[Function("MultiOutput")]
public static MyOutputType Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
FunctionContext context)
{
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.WriteString("Success!"); 
    string myQueueOutput = "some output";
    return new MyOutputType()
    {
        Name = myQueueOutput,
        HttpResponse = response
    };
    }
}
public class MyOutputType
{
    [QueueOutput("myQueue")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Refer [.NET isolated process guide for .NET 5.0 in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#multiple-output-bindings)

Thanks @ [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)

I had tried with SeviceBus Client to send a multiple messages to a queue I am able to process it.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-dotnet)